# what are the flat tables created by magento system while indexing?

Tags: magento-1.9, indexing, flat

How magento creates flat tables and what are the entities that are converted to flat table?

1. Can you list all the flat tables created by magento?
2. What are the events which lead to indexing required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205714/list-of-tables-to-safely-truncate-in-magento

mostly the following tables can be truncted,

```
core_cache
core_cache_option
core_cache_tag
log_customer
log_quote
log_summary
log_summary_type
log_url
log_url_info
log_visitor
log_visitor_info
log_visitor_online
enterprise_logging_event
enterprise_logging_event_changes
index_event
index_process_event
report_event
report_viewed_product_index
dataflow_batch_export
dataflow_batch_import
```